# Passing Javascript map from aura controller to Apex Controller - Not working

Tags: apex, javascript, aura, map

I'm passing below Javascript map from aura component controller to apex controller but map is showing empty in debug log.

```
var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3}
```

Aura component controller

```
var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3}

var action= component.get('c.updateSortOrder');

action.setParams(
{"mapofIdSortOrder" : obj}
);
```

Apex controller

```
@AuraEnabled

public static void updateSortOrder(Map<String,Integer> mapofIdSortOrder){

  system.debug('mapofIdSortOrder size---'+ mapofIdSortOrder.size());

}
```

Map<String,Integer> mapofIdSortOrder is showing empty in debug log in salesforce.

Seems it's not getting correctly passed from aura controller.

Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: in aura controller are you doing `$A.enqueueAction(action);`

Comment: @AmanPatil  Yes.. I figured it out.

If I'm trying to pass the map in below format, it's not working.

var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3}


Rather below format is working fine.

obj["0QL8W000006RHl1WAG"] = 1;
obj["0QL8W000006RHl0WAG"] = 2;
obj["0QL8W000006RHl2WAG"] = 3;

Any idea how can I convert it to above format ?
Do I have to run any for loop to get this format ?

Comment: try changing the obj to `var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG': 1, '0QL8W000006RHl0WAG': 2, '0QL8W000006RHl2WAG': 3};` see if this works

Comment: @AmanPatil That's the answer that you should add. I don't need the rep :D

Comment: @sfdcfox  How can I convert the below format to the required one ?

var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3} 

var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG':1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG':2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG':3} 

Please help.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I believe you're asking the wrong question. Where is `{'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3}` coming from? My guess is that you were trying to return a map from another Apex method, but used something like `return ''+myMapData` instead of `JSON.serialize(myMapData)`, so you have the `=>` that Apex uses rather than the `:` that is expected. This is a classic [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). We might need to take a step or two back. Can you please [edit] in more background information?

Comment: @sfdcfox

I need to pass a map as parameter to the apex controller.
When I'm passing in below format, the map is showing empty in debug log.


var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3}

I think it should be in below format

var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG':1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG':2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG':3}


Apex Controller

public static void updateSortOrder(Map<String,Integer> mapofId_SortOrder){
        system.debug('mapofId_SortOrder size---'+mapofId_SortOrder.size());
}

The above map is showing empty in debug log.
Please help

Comment: @ParvindraSingh Assuming that's not a typo, you have `mapofId_SortOrder` in your Apex, but `mapofIdSortOrder` in your JavaScript. Make sure you check the variable names.

Comment: @sfdcfox  Variable names are correct at both the places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is think is the Obj that you are referring is a map type is JS

you can convert that Map to Object with below code

```
var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3}

const newObj = Object.fromEntries(obj);

var action= component.get('c.updateSortOrder');

action.setParams(
{"mapofIdSortOrder" : newObj}
);        


action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        // handle success
    } else if (state === "ERROR") {
        // handle error
    }
});

$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: Do you have the javascript code to convert the '=>' to  ':' ?

Please help.

Comment: I have edited the answer see if this works

Comment: @AmanPatil That won't work--`{x=>y}` is not valid JavaScript, so this answer can't possibly be the solution.

Comment: @sfdcfox i think he is referring the `obj` as a map in JS that needs to be converted as a valid JS object

Comment: @AmanPatil  I'm getting internal server error in toast message.

Don't know what's going wrong.

Aura Controller
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(theMap);
console.log('newObj----',newObj);            
//newObj----  {0QL8W000006RHl1WAG:1,0QL8W000006RHl0WAG:2,0QL8W000006RHl2WAG:3}

 var action = component.get("c.updateSortOrder");
 action.setParams({"mapofId_SortOrder" : newObj});

Apex Controller

public static void updateSortOrder(Map<Id,Integer> mapofId_SortOrder){
        system.debug('mapofId_SortOrder size---'+mapofId_SortOrder.size());        
}


Please help

Comment: First of all tell me how are you creating this `var obj = {'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG'=>1,'0QL8W000006RHl0WAG'=>2,'0QL8W000006RHl2WAG'=>3}`  as far as i know you asked a question regarding this right ?

Comment: in `Console.log(newObj)` are you able to see `newObj` value in your aura controller and what are the values you are able to see ?

Comment: @AmanPatil   Thanks a ton Aman.. It's working now :)